# React Native: How does usage of nested components affect performance?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Let's say I have a FlatList component that renders items whose counts can be anywhere between 10 to 100+.

The [official doc](https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration) on FlatList optimization says "Try to avoid a lot of logic and nesting in your list items." I want to understand better what this actually means.

For the item components, I have a couple of options (Examples are simplified, the actual components are much more complicated obviously):

Option 1: Using a nested structure, e.g. :

```
const ItemComponent = (props) => {

    const ChildComponent1 = (props) => {
        return (
            <View>
                <Image source={props.image}/>
            </View>
        )
    }

    const ChildComponent2 = () => {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>This is Child Component.</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>This is {props.name} </Text>
            <ChildComponent1 image={props.image}/>
            <ChildComponent2/>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Option 2: Using a non-nested structure, e.g. :

```
const ItemComponent = (props) => {

    return (
        <View>
            <Text>This is {props.name} </Text>
            <View>
                <Image source={props.image}/>
            </View>
            <View>
                <Text>This is Child Component.</Text>
            </View>
        </View>
    )
}
```

1. Am I actually better off in terms of performance if I use option 2?
2. If so, how much performance gain will I have and why? I'd like to understand deeper, but cannot find a resources that explains the rationale in detail.

Thanks!

Comment: You could try it! Performance hits should be more obvious in debug mode. Load up 1000 nested and scroll around etc, do the same with 1000 that have the flat structure. My guess is the final number of elements in the component will be much more of a factor than the structure, but I don't have the data to back that up. If you do try it, it would be great to know your results.

Comment: I think you can set the option `initialNumToRender` with the value that enough fill the screen

Comment: It seems one aspect is: the unmount of the nested component. \
> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2sAdzy90GtE \
Another aspect can be: unable to compare nested component type in fiber \
> (forgot reference) \
(not sure about other aspects & designs)